# C# Bitwise Operators On char

Tags: c#, char, bit-manipulation

I have some old C code that is being converted to C#. There is a lot of bitwise operators such as this

```
const unsigned char N = 0x10;
char C;
.....
if (C & N)
{
   .....
}
```

What would be the equivalent of this in C#? For example, the first line is invalid in C# as the compiler says there is no conversion from int to char. Nor is unsigned a valid operator in C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
const char N = (char)0x10;
```

or

```
const char N = '\x10';
```

and

```
if ((C & N) != 0) // Be aware the != has precedence on &, so you need ()
{
}
```

but be aware that `char` in C is 1 byte, in C# it's 2 bytes, so perhaps you should use `byte`

```
const byte N = 0x10;
```

but perhaps you want to use flags, so you could use `enum`:

```
[Flags]
enum MyEnum : byte
{
    N = 0x10
}

MyEnum C;

if (C.HasFlag(MyEnum.N))
{
}
```

(note that [Enum.HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) was introduced in C# 4.0)

Comment: Thanks for that. I like the Flag option as it is more readable.